# Can't query parse custom class named "User" (Cloud Code)

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getfullname", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var Child = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Child);
//var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    var name = "";
    //response.success(results.length);
    console.log(results);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        name = results[i].get("fullName");
    }
    response.success([results.length,name]);
   },
   error: function() {
    response.error("movie lookup failed");
   }
  });
});
```

[{"topScore":199,"twitterId":"123345566","username":"wagih","objectId":"53qx8hKBvV","createdAt":"2014-12-10T13:25:05.606Z","updatedAt":"2014-12-10T13:25:34.510Z","__type":"Object","className":"_User"}

as you can see the parse log is referring to Parse.User (_User) not my custom one
so any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SDK v1.0.2 we added the ability to subclass Parse.User with Parse.Object.extend("User").

(See Javascript changelog: https://parse.com/docs/downloads)

And hence, you should use our predefined _User class or rename your custom class to something else.

Thanks to

Ibrahim Faour From Facebook Team